# Inconsistent views on new design

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The new design is great, but it has an inconsistent view. The "Front Page" view has 4 columns: Votes, Answers, Views, Question Title. The "Questions" view has 2 columns: Votes, Answers and Views on the same column, and the Question Title on the secondth one:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with the design, that's just the way the sites are all set up.

You should open that on http://meta.stackoverflow.com if you have a more substantive critique.